# How get loc from the multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas

My Dataframe is from groupby is below

```
                             QTY
Store_type      prod_cat    

Flagship        Bags        2726
                Books       14766
                Clothing    5844
                Electronics 9950
MBR             Bags        2936
                Books       14868
                Clothing    6198
                Footwear    6105
TeleShop        Bags        2854
                Books       13836
```

- Q1: How to get  "Books" and "Clothing" categories from Flagship Stores
- Q2: How to get the categories QTY sold > 5000 from each store

Expected Out 
Q1

```
Flagship Books  14766
         Clothing   5844
```

Q2

```
Flagship        Books       14766
                Clothing    5844
                Electronics 9950
MBR             Books       14868
                Clothing    6198
                Footwear    6105
TeleShop        Books       13836
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 posted the Expected out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with list of tuples:

```
df1 = df.loc[[('Flagship','Books'), ('Flagship','Clothing')]]
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Store_type == 'Flagship' & prod_cat in ['Books','Clothing']")
```

---

```
print (df1)
                       QTY
Store_type prod_cat       
Flagship   Books     14766
           Clothing   5844
```

And for filtering use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df['QTY'] > 5000]
#alternative
#df2 = df.query("QTY > 5000")
print (df2)
                          QTY
Store_type prod_cat          
Flagship   Books        14766
           Clothing      5844
           Electronics   9950
MBR        Books        14868
           Clothing      6198
           Footwear      6105
TeleShop   Books        13836
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may use `axis` option of `loc` for question 1

```
df.loc(axis=0)['Flagship', ['Books','Clothing']]


                       qty
Store_type prod_cat
Flagship   Books     14766
           Clothing   5844
```

On question 2, simply `df[df['QTY'] > 5000]`. It is already the straightest way..